# PHP and WordPress upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I will be updating our WordPress sites this weekend and I was wondering what might be the best versions to go to.  Of course, the latest would be best in theory but sometimes there are bugs that have not been worked out yet so we haven't always gone to the latest and greatest.

We host internally on IIS.  I have 3 sites and need to upgrade WordPress (current version 5.7.6) and wasn't sure whether to go to 5.8, 5.9 or 6.  I also need to upgrade PHP (current version 7.4.21) and thinking about 7.4.28 or 8.

I was just trying to get some thoughts.  If the general consensus is 6.0 and 8.0 that's fine.  I don't have any custom code or rely on a lot of plugins.  The only plugins I'm concerned about are Subscribe2 and Active Directory Integration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try to update your PHP, WordPress, and plugins separately on Dev environment and test each stage manually or using utility as a screaming frog.

Also, you can use next instrument https://psalm.dev/ , that helps you to check the compatibility of your code with a concrete PHP version.